# Leaflet Providing invalid Lng/Lat coordinates when location duplicates on display

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

**Question**

Is the lng/lat provided by leaflet not a GPS coordinate?  Do I have a way to convert it into GPS coordinates or is this a bug in leaflet?

**Steps to reproduce**

Setup a map that repeats. Click on the repeating section, the click event will return diffent and often invalid coordinates.

**Expected behavior**

The correct (repeated) coordinate would be provided for each GPS location, regardless if it repeats on the display.

**Code to show error**

Simply bind a click event

```
L.map(name, {fullscreenControl: true}).fitWorld().zoomIn().on("click", selectorConfirm);

function selectorConfirm = function(e) {
console.log('selected:'+e.latlng.lat+','+e.latlng.lng);
}
```

**Minimal example reproducing the issue**

https://www.hikerock.com/rock/210/

Click on map -> the console log will output what the gps coordinates are provided by leaflet.

The code is super simple, if you need to access it :

https://www.hikerock.com/plugin/map/js/map.min.js?cache=6x3cWuxp

function map() => inits leaflet
map.prototype.selectorConfirm () -> is what is collects the event, is doing the console.logging

Comment: Sounds like you refer to a known limitation of Leaflet, see https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4919

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is how Leaflet is designed :

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/1885

It can be addressed by using :

```
e.latlng.wrap();
e.latlng.wrap().lat;
```